# TYPO3: Sort elements in list view

Tags: sorting, listview, typo3, frontend

I wish to sort elements in the list view.
Found something like `default_sortby`.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_tag'] = array(
    'ctrl' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_tag']['ctrl'],
    'interface' => array( ...
```

How do I add the `default_sortby` to the `ctrl` without removing the `$GLOBALS['TCA']...` array-thingy?

**Plus:** Will this work and output the elements in the frontend list view alphabetically sorted?

```
'default_sortby' => 'ORDER BY name DESC',
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regarding your first question:

The definition of `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']` should also be in your extensions source code, probably in the file `ext_tables.php` at the extension root. Add the default sorting there.

#### Regarding the second question:

The setting `default_sortby` in the `TCA` does not affect the queries generated by extbase. You have to define the sortings in the frontend by setting the ordering in the repository.

Comment: Unfortunately `default_sortby` doesn't affect Extbase queries and it's required to define it in repository (i.e in the `initializeObject()` method)